# Expo cannot read files from filesystem directory on ios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am rendering images after cropping it into squares using `ImageManipulator` then saving it to file system the issue is i can't render images from filesystem on ios but on android it works fine this is a snap shot of my code

```
        const img = 'https://url.com/do720ahaw3zerqcychmu.jpg';
        await Image.getSize(img, (width, height) => {
            this.setState({ width, height })
        })

        let imageWidth = this.state.width / 3;
        let imageHieght = this.state.height / 3;

        let list = [];
        let crop = {};

        for (let iHeight = 0; iHeight < 3; iHeight++) {
            for (let iWidth = 0; iWidth < 3; iWidth++) {
                let pointX = iWidth * imageWidth;
                let pointY = iHeight * imageHieght;
                crop = {
                    originY: pointY,
                    originX: pointX,
                    // originX: (-(this.crop.originX - 46.875) * 3) / this.crop.scale,
                    width: imageWidth,
                    height: imageHieght
                };
                const data = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(img, [{ crop }], { format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.JPEG });

                list.push({ img: data.uri });
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you resolve this? apparently there's a fix described here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4806 but I'm still getting the same 'this file isn't readable' error on iOS. Android works fine.

Comment: Nah unfortunately, Exactly it works fine on android

Comment: I was having issues with writing to file-system on iOS with expo-filesystem. Android worked fine. I was attempting to use directories, but if I just dumped the files into FS.documentDirectory directly, it worked fine on iOS.